# Artinian ring and faithful module of finite length

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a ring. How can I prove that:

> $A$ is an Artinian ring $\Leftrightarrow \exists$ a faithful $A$-module which is of finite length.

I know that if a ring has a faithful $A$-module which is Noetherian, then the ring is Noetherian. Can I use this to prove the result above? I need your help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50178/are-artinian-modules-over-non-artinian-rings-relevant

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you must intend this for commutative rings, because it doesn't hold for general noncommutative rings.

The answer to the question follows from the same argument here [in Manny Reyes's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/258141/29335).

If the faithful and finite length module is $M$, then the trick is just to embed $R$ into $M^n$. As a submodule of an Artinian module, it is also then Artinian.

---

Added more detail: Since $M$ has finite length, it has a finite generating set $m_1,\dots m_n$. Look at the map $R\to M^n$ given by $r\mapsto (m_1r,m_2r,m_3r,\dots,m_nr)$. Since $M$ is faithful, this map is an injection. Since $M$ is Artinian, so is $M^n$. Thus, $R$ is a submodule of an Artinian module, and hence is Artinian itself.

The converse is obvious since if $R$ is Artinian, then it itself is a faithful $R$ module of finite length.

Comment: I don't understand if I change Artinian for Noetherian in the solution that you say me. You can explain it, please

Comment: @rgl4 I added to the solution to address your comment.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the solution but the implication right has not proved not?

Comment: @rgl4 I don't understand. I think (but I can't remember, since you edited it) that your last comment asked for this implication. Can you be more clear?

Comment: @rgl4 It's not enough for the module to be Artinian, it has to be finite length. This is because an Artinian module need not have a finite generating set, but one of finite length (which is Noetherian) must have a finite generating set.

Comment: To see if I understand the solution:
The implication $\Rightarrow$ is obvious and it doesn't more explications.
And the implication $\Leftarrow$ will be:

I call $M$ an $A$-module finitelly generated and faithful.

So $M$ is finitelly generated then exists a finite set of generators $m_1 , ... , m_n$.

If I consider the homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow M^n$ given by $a \mapsto (m_1 a, ... , m_n a)$ how $M$ is faithful, then $f$ is injective.

(Why I can say that $M$ is artinian?) If $M$ is artinian then $M^n$ is artinian.

Therefore, $A$ is a submodule of an Artinian module, so $A$ is Artinian.

Comment: I could say that $M$ is Artinian because $M$ has finite length, not?

Comment: @rgl4 Correct, a module has finite length iff it is Artinian and Noetherian. A submodule of an Artinian module is Artinian.