# Why is $A/\mathrm{ann}(M)$ necessarily Artinian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a finitely generated Artinian module over a commutative ring $A$.  Why is $A/\mathrm{ann}(M)$ Artinian?

Comment: This is probably another duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/378563/29335

Comment: That link explains that if M is generated by n elements, the R embeds into $M^n$, which is Artinian. Since a submodule of an Artinian module is Artinian, R is Artinian.